# Volume of an $n$-dimensional ellipsoid

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, volume

Consider the convex body $S_r \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ defined as follows

$$S_r := \{ \mathbb{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n : \| A \mathbb{x}\| \leq r \}$$

for some invertible $n \times n$ matrix $A$ and some real constant $r > 0$. Here, $\|\cdot \|$ denotes the Euclidean norm. How is the volume of $S_r$ calculated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that the Lebesgue measure and the Euclidean norm are rotation invariant.

Note that $x \in S_r$ **iff** $|x^T A^TA x| \le r$ and since $A^TA$ is symmetric
and positive definite there is a unitary $U$ and a diagonal $\Lambda$
such that $A^TA = U \Lambda U^T$.

Hence the volume of $S_r$ is the same as the volume of $\{x | \sum_k \lambda_k x_k^2 \le r^2 \} =  \{x | \sum_k ({ \sqrt{\lambda_k} x_k})^2 \le r^2 \} = \{({r x_1 \over \sqrt{\lambda_1}},...,{r x_n \over \sqrt{\lambda_n}}) | \|x\| \le 1 \}$.

It is straightforward to see that the volume of the last set is 
${r^n \over \sqrt{\lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n}} = {r^n \over |\det A|}$ times the
volume of the unit ball $\overline{B}(0,1)$.

Hence the problem reduces to that of finding the volume of the unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

**Addendum**: Given a measurable set $A$ and a map $L(x) = (x_1,...,\lambda x_k, ...,x_n)$ (exactly one of the coordinates is multiplied by $\lambda$), it
is straightforward to show that $m(L(A)) = |\lambda| m(A)$. Since the map
$x \mapsto ({r x_1 \over \sqrt{\lambda_1}},...,{r x_n \over \sqrt{\lambda_n}})$
can be written as the composition of $n$ such operations, we see that
\begin{eqnarray}
m(\{({r x_1 \over \sqrt{\lambda_1}},...,{r x_n \over \sqrt{\lambda_n}}) | \|x\| \le 1 \}) &=& |{r \over \sqrt{\lambda_1}}|m(\{(x_1,...,{r x_n \over \sqrt{\lambda_n}}) | \|x\| \le 1 \}) \\
&\vdots& \\
&=& {r^n \over \sqrt{\lambda_1 \cdots \lambda_n}} m( \{ x | \|x\| \le 1 \}) 
\end{eqnarray}

**And more**:

To see why $m(L(A)) = |\lambda| m(A)$ for a measurable $A$, we use the definition of Lebesgue outer measure. We have
$m(A) = \inf \{ \sum_k m(R_k) | \{R_k\}_k \text{ is a cover of }A \text{ by rectangles}\}$.

It is not difficult to see that $m(L(R)) = |\lambda| m(R)$ for a rectangle.

If ${\cal R}_A= \{ \{R_k\}_k |  \{R_k\}_k \text{ is a cover of }A \text{ by rectangles}\} $, then it is straightforward to see that
${\cal R}_{L(A)} = \{ \{L(R_k)\}_k | \{R_k\}_k \in {\cal R}_A \}$.

Hence $m(L(A)) = \inf \{ \sum_k m(L(R_k)) | \{R_k\}_k \text{ is a cover of }A \text{ by rectangles}\} = |\lambda| m(A)$.

Comment: I don't see that finding out the volume of the last set is straightforward. How do you do that without integrating?

Comment: @amsmath: Do you mean the one with $\|x\| \le 1$?

Comment: @amsmath: I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, at some level computing the measure of a set is essentially integrating. In any event, I elaborated the computation of the last set, hopefully that is what you were asking?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply - thanks for the answer @copper.hat!

Comment: @copper.hat I just wondered whether you wrote that answer although I have already given one. In fact, even when you say that proving $m(L(A)) = |\lambda|m(A)$ is straightforward, you will have to use the integral transformation formula in my answer. And I don't know whether Chris is aware of that since he marked your answer.

Comment: @amsmath: I saw your answer, but gave an alternative that doesn't use the change of variables formula. Why do you ask? The property I mentioned follows from the usual definition of Lebesgue measure and does **not** involve integration in the sense you seem to imply. The usual proofs of the change of variable theorem actually depend on this more elementary result.

Comment: @copper.hat Then how do you show in an elementary way that $m(L(A)) = |\lambda|m(A)$? If you can do it elementary without the change of variables formula, I totally agree.

Comment: @amsmath: It follows from the fact that if $R$ is a rectangle that the basic formula (product of sides) then the (unsigned) volume of $L(R)$ is $|\lambda|$ times the volume of $R$. I am guessing that the OP is working from a more geometric than analytic viewpoint. The change of variables formula is very useful, but overkill here.

Comment: @amsmath: The proof of the change of variables formula usually starts by showing $m(A)= |\det(L)| m(L(A))$ for elementary matrices...

Comment: @copper.hat And is that straightforward?

Comment: @amsmath: I am not sure what you are driving at here? Yes, it is very straightforward. It is certainly more straightforward than proving the change of variables formula, and comes from our basic intuition that when you scale an axis that the a volume is similarly scaled.

Comment: @copper.hat Well, it's not my intuition at least. This is clear if $A$ is a rectangle, but for just an arbitrary measurable set, I don't have any intuition. Of course, you boiled the whole thing down to a simpler problem. However, I am not sure whether proving the last bit is also "straightforward" for Chris.

Comment: @amsmath: If it is clear for a rectangle then it follows immediately for other measurable sets from the outer measure definition.

Comment: @copper.hat This I don't see. How do I use the properties of an outer measure and the fact that the claim holds for rectangles in order to show that it holds for all measurable sets? Guess I am missing something obvious...

Comment: @amsmath: I added an elaboration. Broadly, if something suitable holds for the rectangles then it holds for the $\sigma$-field generated by the rectangles.

Comment: @copper.hat Thank you very much. This explains a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Use the substitution rule (where $\phi : B\to\phi(B)$ is a diffeomorphism)
$$
\int_{\phi(B)}f(x)\,dx = \int_Bf(\phi(y))|\det\phi'(y)|\,dy.
$$
Here, $B = B_r(0)$ (the ball with radius $r$ and center $0$) and $\phi(y) = A^{-1}y$.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @amsmath!